# Symfony 2.0 login does not work with Symfony 2.1?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

Is there something special I need to do, because I have three applications on Symfony 2.0 and after the login I can use any of those apps, but one Symfony 2.1 app does not work (does not authenticate) and it asks me to login. If I do that, Symfony 2.0 apps are logged out.

Has the authentication system changed radically? How do I adapt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes

`Security SF 2.0` http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/security.html

`Security SF 2.1` http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

**Security system is not downwardly compatible.**

Many thanks to [**Stony**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411918/stony), Upgrade How To: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md#security

By default, Symfony2 relies on a cookie (the Session) to persist the security context of the user. So maybe SF2.1 login overwrites your cookie and destroies previous created sessions.

Have a look at Stateless authentication http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/security.html#stateless-authentication

Comment: Wait -- are you saying that I can't get my applications to work together if I upgrade to Symfony 2.1? I can't have Symfony 2.0 and 2.1 apps all "logged in"?

Comment: I am not sure how your applications work together, however you should not mix up the authentication, this won't work. E.g. you cannot expect SF2.1 app to login when you are actually using SF2.0 login procedure. You need a seperate login for SF2.1.

Comment: I don't want stateless authentication. I just want the Symfony 2.1 login to work with Symfony 2.0

Answer (score 2):

Yes from **Symfony 2.0 to 2.1** are some changes that have effekt on your system.

Here is the upgrade introduction with some changes in the Security configuration.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md